# Using array passed by Ajax in php to Insert record to MYSQL database table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, ajax

I have a javascript function, called by an SVG element, to pass 2 variables and a multi-dimensional array to a php file. The php file will then use the passed data to create a record in one MYSQL table and several records in another table - using the passed variables (array and 2 variables).

The data for the single variables is passed by AJAX ok and I can use it to successfully create a record in the Exercise table.

The data for the array is also passed with no errors. I have tested that there is data before passing with AJAX - see function code.

The Javascript Console shows NO errors. I believe that I have used JSON correctly to encode and decode the array.

But NO MYSQL records are created using data from the array. I suspect that I am not using the decoded array correctly. Just confused as to why one two pieces of data are passed ok and the array is not.

Any help appreciated - Charlie

Please see  code:
Javascript function

```
function createexercise(id)
{
    pathways = <?php echo json_encode($myarray) ?>;

    for (var x=1;x<=15;x++)//loops through pathway array and makes each pathway non visible
        {
            document.getElementById(x).style.visibility = "hidden";
        }//for loop scope

    document.getElementById(id).style.visibility="hidden";
    var z=0;
    var SPX=0;
    var SPY=0;
    var EPX=0;
    var EPY=0;

        for(var x=0;x<=newpath.length-1;x++)//cycle through exercise pathways
        {               
            for (var y=0;y<=pathways.length-1; y++)// cycle through ALL pathways possible
            {               
                if(y==0)//if first possible pathway add Start X coordinate to Start Y coordinate
                {
                    pathwayselected=pathwayselected+pathways[y][3]+","+pathways[y][4]+" ";          
                }//if scope

                z=pathways[y][0];
                SPX=pathways[y][3];
                SPY=pathways[y][4];
                EPX=pathways[y][5];
                EPY=pathways[y][6];

                if(z==newpath[x] && y>0)//if first possible pathway add Start X coordinate to Start Y coordinate to End X and Y coordinates
                {
                    var selected = document.getElementById(newpath[z]);
                    pathwayselected=pathwayselected+" L"+SPX+","+SPY+" L"+EPX+","+EPY+" ";
                }//if scope
            }//y loop scope                         
        }//x loop scope

        // Test to show that the "pathways" array is data populated
        for(q=5; q<6; q++)
        {
        alert("Pathway ID element is....:"+pathways[q][0]);
        alert("Pathway Start ID element is....:"+pathways[q][1]);
        alert("Pathway End IDelement is....:"+pathways[q][2]);
        alert("Pathway Start X Coord element is....:"+pathways[q][3]);
        alert("Pathway Start Y Coord element is....:"+pathways[q][4]);
        alert("Pathway End X Coord element is....:"+pathways[q][5]);
        alert("Pathway End Y Coord element is....:"+pathways[q][6]);    
        }

        // Then the Exercise ID and the pathway string that has been built is sent to a PHP file to create a
        // mysql database "Exercise" record and a series of "Exercise Pathway" records

        var exid = parseInt(id);   

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "InsertExercisePathsSecure.php",
        data: {'id': exid, 'PathSelected': pathwayselected,'data' : pathways}, 
        cache: false,

        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            alert("OK we are back");
        },      
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
            {   alert("Error code is....:"+xhr.status); }
        });//s.ajax outer scope

    var rect = document.getElementById("start");
    rect.style.visibility="visible";
    var rectt1 = document.getElementById("t1");
    rectt1.style.visibility="visible"

  }//end of function createexercise scope
```

php file - InsertExercisePathsSecure.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
</head>

<?php
# Fill our variables to set up environment

$dbname = '???????';
$dbuser = '???????';
$dbpass = '???????';
$dbhost = '???????';

# set the database connection to be used using php function
$conn=mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////
// allocate php variables to $_POST[] data received
///////////////////////////////////////////////////

$EID = $_POST['id'];
$PathData = $_POST['PathSelected'];
$data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']));

///////////////////////////////////////////////////
// create mysql query using php variables and then execute it
///////////////////////////////////////////////////

mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO ExerciseTable (ExerciseID, PathwayData)
VALUES ('$EID', '$PathData')"); 

///////////////////////////////////////////////////
// loop through received decoded array and allocate php variables to
each element field
// after variable allocation execute mysql process
///////////////////////////////////////////////////    

for ($x=0; $x<15; $x++)
{
    $PID = $data[$x][0];
    $TL = $data[$x][2];
    $EP = $data[$x][3];
    $ROW = $data[$x][4];
    $PS = $data[$x][5];

    mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO ExercisePathwayTable (ExerciseID,
    PathwayID, tablelocator, ExercisePathway, Row, PathwaySequence)
    VALUES('$EID','$PID','$TL','$EP','$ROW','$PS')");

 }
mysqli_close($conn);

?>
</body>
</html>



  [Log]     <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0
 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1- 
 transitional.dtd"> (SVGDOMCreate.php, line 194)
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
  />
    <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    </head>

    array(3) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(2) "18"
  ["PathSelected"]=>
  string(52) "M 100,60  L195,60 L330,490 100,60  L330,60 L330,490 "
  ["data"]=>
  array(16) {
    [0]=>
    array(14) {
      [0]=>
      string(1) "1"
      [1]=>
      string(1) "1"
      [2]=>
      string(1) "2"
      [3]=>
      string(3) "100"
      [4]=>
      string(2) "60"
      [5]=>
      string(3) "100"
      [6]=>
      string(3) "490"
      ["PathwayID"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["StartPathwayID"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["EndPathwayID"]=>
      string(1) "2"
      ["StartPathwayXCoord"]=>
      string(3) "100"
      ["StartPathwayYCoord"]=>
      string(2) "60"
      ["EndPathwayXCoord"]=>
      string(3) "100"
      ["EndPathwayYCoord"]=>
      string(3) "490"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(14) {
      [0]=>
      string(1) "2"
      [1]=>
      string(1) "1"
      [2]=>
      string(1) "4"
      [3]=>
      string(3) "100"
      [4]=>
      string(2) "60"
      [5]=>
      string(3) "195"
      [6]=>
      string(3) "490"
      ["PathwayID"]=>
      string(1) "2"
      ["StartPathwayID"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["EndPathwayID"]=>
      string(1) "4"
      ["StartPathwayXCoord"]=>
      string(3) "100"
      ["StartPathwayYCoord"]=>
      string(2) "60"
      ["EndPathwayXCoord"]=>
      string(3) "195"
      ["EndPathwayYCoord"]=>
      string(3) "490"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(14) {
      [0]=>
      string(1) "3"
      [1]=>
      string(1) "1"
      [2]=>
      string(1) "6"
      [3]=>
      string(3) "100"
      [4]=>
      string(2) "60"
      [5]=>
      string(3) "330"
      [6]=>
      string(3) "490"
      ["PathwayID"]=>
      string(1) "3"
      ["StartPathwayID"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["EndPathwayID"]=>
      string(1) "6"
      ["StartPathwayXCoord"]=>
      string(3) "100"
      ["StartPathwayYCoord"]=>
      string(2) "60"
      ["EndPathwayXCoord"]=>
      string(3) "330"
      ["EndPathwayYCoord"]=>
      string(3) "490"
    }
    [3]=>
    array(14) {
      [0]=>
      string(1) "4"
      [1]=>
      string(1) "3"
      [2]=>
      string(1) "2"
      [3]=>
      string(3) "195"
      [4]=>
      string(2) "60"
      [5]=>
      string(3) "100"
      [6]=>
      string(3) "490"
      ["PathwayID"]=>
      string(1) "4"
      ["StartPathwayID"]=>
      string(1) "3"
      ["EndPathwayID"]=>
      string(1) "2"
      ["StartPathwayXCoord"]=>
      string(3) "195"
      ["StartPathwayYCoord"]=>
      string(2) "60"
      ["EndPathwayXCoord"]=>
      string(3) "100"
      ["EndPathwayYCoord"]=>
      string(3) "490"
    }
    [4]=>
    array(14) {
      [0]=>
      string(1) "5"
      [1]=>
      string(1) "3"
      [2]=>
      string(1) "4"
      [3]=>
      string(3) "195"
      [4]=>
      string(2) "60"
      [5]=>
      string(3) "195"
      [6]=>
      string(3) "490"
      ["PathwayID"]=>
      string(1) "5"
      ["StartPathwayID"]=>
      string(1) "3"
      ["EndPathwayID"]=>
      string(1) "4"
      ["StartPathwayXCoord"]=>
      string(3) "195"
      ["StartPathwayYCoord"]=>
      string(2) "60"
      ["EndPathwayXCoord"]=>
      string(3) "195"
      ["EndPathwayYCoord"]=>
      string(3) "490"
    }
    [5]=>
    array(14) {
      [0]=>
      string(1) "6"
      [1]=>
      string(1) "3"
      [2]=>
      string(1) "6"
      [3]=>
      string(3) "195"
      [4]=>
      string(2) "60"
      [5]=>
      string(3) "330"
      [6]=>
      string(3) "490"
      ["PathwayID"]=>
      string(1) "6"
      ["StartPathwayID"]=>
      string(1) "3"
      ["EndPathwayID"]=>
      string(1) "6"
      ["StartPathwayXCoord"]=>
      string(3) "195"
      ["StartPathwayYCoord"]=>
      string(2) "60"
      ["EndPathwayXCoord"]=>
      string(3) "330"
      ["EndPathwayYCoord"]=>
      string(3) "490"
    }
    [6]=>
    array(14) {
      [0]=>
      string(1) "7"
      [1]=>
      string(1) "5"
      [2]=>
      string(1) "2"
      [3]=>
      string(3) "330"
      [4]=>
      string(2) "60"
      [5]=>
      string(3) "100"
      [6]=>
      string(3) "490"
      ["PathwayID"]=>
      string(1) "7"
      ["StartPathwayID"]=>
      string(1) "5"
      ["EndPathwayID"]=>
      string(1) "2"
      ["StartPathwayXCoord"]=>
      string(3) "330"
      ["StartPathwayYCoord"]=>
      string(2) "60"
      ["EndPathwayXCoord"]=>
      string(3) "100"
      ["EndPathwayYCoord"]=>
      string(3) "490"
    }
    [7]=>
    array(14) {
      [0]=>
      string(1) "8"
      [1]=>
      string(1) "5"
      [2]=>
      string(1) "4"
      [3]=>
      string(3) "330"
      [4]=>
      string(2) "60"
      [5]=>
      string(3) "195"
      [6]=>
      string(3) "490"
      ["PathwayID"]=>
      string(1) "8"
      ["StartPathwayID"]=>
      string(1) "5"
      ["EndPathwayID"]=>
      string(1) "4"
      ["StartPathwayXCoord"]=>
      string(3) "330"
      ["StartPathwayYCoord"]=>
      string(2) "60"
      ["EndPathwayXCoord"]=>
      string(3) "195"
      ["EndPathwayYCoord"]=>
      string(3) "490"
    }
    [8]=>
    array(14) {
      [0]=>
      string(1) "9"
      [1]=>
      string(1) "5"
      [2]=>
      string(1) "6"
      [3]=>
      string(3) "330"
      [4]=>
      string(2) "60"
      [5]=>
      string(3) "330"
      [6]=>
      string(3) "490"
      ["PathwayID"]=>
      string(1) "9"
      ["StartPathwayID"]=>
      string(1) "5"
      ["EndPathwayID"]=>
      string(1) "6"
      ["StartPathwayXCoord"]=>
      string(3) "330"
      ["StartPathwayYCoord"]=>
      string(2) "60"
      ["EndPathwayXCoord"]=>
      string(3) "330"
      ["EndPathwayYCoord"]=>
      string(3) "490"
    }
    [9]=>
    array(14) {
      [0]=>
      string(2) "10"
      [1]=>
      string(1) "7"
      [2]=>
      string(1) "2"
      [3]=>
      string(2) "65"
      [4]=>
      string(2) "25"
      [5]=>
      string(3) "100"
      [6]=>
      string(3) "490"
      ["PathwayID"]=>
      string(2) "10"
      ["StartPathwayID"]=>
      string(1) "7"
      ["EndPathwayID"]=>
      string(1) "2"
      ["StartPathwayXCoord"]=>
      string(2) "65"
      ["StartPathwayYCoord"]=>
      string(2) "25"
      ["EndPathwayXCoord"]=>
      string(3) "100"
      ["EndPathwayYCoord"]=>
      string(3) "490"
    }
    [10]=>
    array(14) {
      [0]=>
      string(2) "11"
      [1]=>
      string(1) "7"
      [2]=>
      string(1) "4"
      [3]=>
      string(2) "65"
      [4]=>
      string(2) "25"
      [5]=>
      string(3) "195"
      [6]=>
      string(3) "490"
      ["PathwayID"]=>
      string(2) "11"
      ["StartPathwayID"]=>
      string(1) "7"
      ["EndPathwayID"]=>
      string(1) "4"
      ["StartPathwayXCoord"]=>
      string(2) "65"
      ["StartPathwayYCoord"]=>
      string(2) "25"
      ["EndPathwayXCoord"]=>
      string(3) "195"
      ["EndPathwayYCoord"]=>
      string(3) "490"
    }
    [11]=>
    array(14) {
      [0]=>
      string(2) "12"
      [1]=>
      string(1) "7"
      [2]=>
      string(1) "6"
      [3]=>
      string(2) "65"
      [4]=>
      string(2) "25"
      [5]=>
      string(3) "330"
      [6]=>
      string(3) "490"
      ["PathwayID"]=>
      string(2) "12"
      ["StartPathwayID"]=>
      string(1) "7"
      ["EndPathwayID"]=>
      string(1) "6"
      ["StartPathwayXCoord"]=>
      string(2) "65"
      ["StartPathwayYCoord"]=>
      string(2) "25"
      ["EndPathwayXCoord"]=>
      string(3) "330"
      ["EndPathwayYCoord"]=>
      string(3) "490"
    }
    [12]=>
    array(14) {
      [0]=>
      string(2) "13"
      [1]=>
      string(1) "8"
      [2]=>
      string(1) "6"
      [3]=>
      string(3) "360"
      [4]=>
      string(2) "25"
      [5]=>
      string(3) "330"
      [6]=>
      string(3) "490"
      ["PathwayID"]=>
      string(2) "13"
      ["StartPathwayID"]=>
      string(1) "8"
      ["EndPathwayID"]=>
      string(1) "6"
      ["StartPathwayXCoord"]=>
      string(3) "360"
      ["StartPathwayYCoord"]=>
      string(2) "25"
      ["EndPathwayXCoord"]=>
      string(3) "330"
      ["EndPathwayYCoord"]=>
      string(3) "490"
    }
    [13]=>
    array(14) {
      [0]=>
      string(2) "14"
      [1]=>
      string(1) "8"
      [2]=>
      string(1) "4"
      [3]=>
      string(3) "360"
      [4]=>
      string(2) "25"
      [5]=>
      string(3) "195"
      [6]=>
      string(3) "490"
      ["PathwayID"]=>
      string(2) "14"
      ["StartPathwayID"]=>
      string(1) "8"
      ["EndPathwayID"]=>
      string(1) "4"
      ["StartPathwayXCoord"]=>
      string(3) "360"
      ["StartPathwayYCoord"]=>
      string(2) "25"
      ["EndPathwayXCoord"]=>
      string(3) "195"
      ["EndPathwayYCoord"]=>
      string(3) "490"
    }
    [14]=>
    array(14) {
      [0]=>
      string(2) "15"
      [1]=>
      string(1) "8"
      [2]=>
      string(1) "2"
      [3]=>
      string(3) "360"
      [4]=>
      string(2) "25"
      [5]=>
      string(3) "100"
      [6]=>
      string(3) "490"
      ["PathwayID"]=>
      string(2) "15"
      ["StartPathwayID"]=>
      string(1) "8"
      ["EndPathwayID"]=>
      string(1) "2"
      ["StartPathwayXCoord"]=>
      string(3) "360"
      ["StartPathwayYCoord"]=>
      string(2) "25"
      ["EndPathwayXCoord"]=>
      string(3) "100"
      ["EndPathwayYCoord"]=>
      string(3) "490"
    }
    [15]=>
    string(5) "false"
  }
}
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Please note the `mysql_` constructor has been **deprecated since 2013**, and is **removed in PHP 7**. This is because it has **serious** security vulnerabilities. **DO NOT USE IT**. If you're using a tutorial that uses it, find a better tutorial. Please consider switching to either [**MySQLi**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead, ensuring that you also use [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to prevent [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) :)

Comment: Hi Thanks - I have been made aware of this recently - I intend to upgrade my sql calls on completion of my site. Thanks

Comment: @Charlie — Stop. Don't waste time building it the wrong way. Fix it now and then use modern code for the rest of the site.

Comment: "I intend to upgrade my sql calls on completion of my site.". Well that's a waste of time because then you'll have to re-write everything and re-test everything. Change it now while it's less hassle.

Comment: Anyway, to debug, check the values of $_POST['data'] in the PHP side, and check what $data looks like. I don't think that what gets sent to the server for that variable is actually going to be JSON.

Comment: Yes you guys are right - just being lazy. Have revised all MYSQL website calls to be MYSQLI. Not too difficult as I only have about 8 types of call to database.

Comment: Not sure how to check the values of my $_POST[data] on the php side as it does not display to screen as its called by the javascript function in another php file

Comment: if you write an `echo`, `print_r` or `var_dump` statement in the PHP then it'll be included in the response to the ajax call, and thus visible when you do `console.log(data);` (or if you look at the ajax call in the browser's dev tools).

Comment: You were right - I put an echo onto the array in php and read back the Console entry for the success function and it only showed the echo command text....Pathway ID is.....:<br>Start PathwayID is.....:<br>End PathwayID is.....:<br>Start X Coord is.....:<br>Start Y Coord is.....:<br>End X Coord is.....:<b

Comment: and NO data. Back to the drawing board to and look to see why the array is not being coded correctly for JSON. Any help appreciated.

Comment: what exactly does your echo statement look like? Are you echoing the whole of $_POST["data"] at once, as I suggested, or trying to get individual bits from it? It might even make sense to just echo the whole of $_POST and check everything. `var_dump($_POST);` is probably going to give the most readable result

Comment: I echo  on all array elements and as mentioned earlier got echo text BUT NO data. Took your advice and put var_dump($_POST); Console log resulting now added to code listing above. 2 simple variables posted ok and have in the past been useable in MYSQL statement

Comment: The data array weirdly does get shown in the console log with each array element showing twice with different field annotators. Data whilst repeated is correct - see code listing for var dump - Ta for help so far

Comment: where is the repetition? Your var_dump output looks fine. It's just showing you the array as both a numeric-indexed and an associative array. You can access the properties by either route. It's not really repeated as such. It's worth noting that it's likely your last sql query will crash because index 15 of the array doesn't contain anything useful, and will likely lead to a malformed query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just realised what I should have realised at the start - you do not have any JSON data.

```
$data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']));
```

should be replaced with

```
$data = $_POST['data'];
```

and then your code will work (except that the last query on index 15 will likely fail since there's no data in that index of $data, you might want to check that).

Your ajax request is sending the data in standard form-urlencoded format. Even though you may have supplied a JavaScript (note, not JSON!) object as the `data:` option in the $.ajax call, jQuery translates and encodes that into a standard data string for you silently. If you were to set a different `contentType` for your ajax, e.g. JSON, then it would convert it to JSON for you, but that's not necessary, and the way you've done it is simpler anyway.

Comment: Many thanks - problems now solved. Now using newer sql calls and AJAX ca this is a great Forum.lls are operative.These give me a great base to move further with my application. Your explanations were informative and educational for me. But I am sure I will be great as